# How to call UIImagePickerController Delegate programmatically or forcefully [without user interaction]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, i have Used UiimagepickerController for taking Video.in bettween my programm received any web service Which belongs to my app, 
i have to stop Video Capture and save video.

i have Used StopVideoCapture to do above thing ,but it doesn't call delegate - `

> (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
>   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

`How to force call above delegate ??.or How to handle interruption Handling in`UIImagePickerController`..  any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The idea with delegate methods is not that you call those methods - "They call you".

So I would not consider calling the delegate method yourself a good practise. However, if you  present the `UIImagePickerViewController` with a modal dialogue (which I guess is common for such a picker) then you can close it like this outside of your delegate method:

```
[[yourPicker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

[Source](http://zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller)

**Update:** You can use the [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for accessing the stored data in your iPhone media library. I recently had to do a similar project where I had to list all images on the iPhone. The Github project [ELCImagePickerController.git](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController.git) was very useful since it shows how the items in your library can be accessed. So you'll do something like this:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

// ....

-(void)fetchPhotoAlbums{

    if(!self.assetsGroups){
        self.assetsGroups = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];      
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        @autoreleasepool {
            void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
                if (group == nil){
                   // Completed
                   [self.delegate pictureService:self fetchedAlbums:returnArray]; 
                    return;
                }

                Album *currentAlbum = [self albumForAssetsGroup:group];

                // Store the Group for later retrieving the pictures for the album
                [self.assetsGroups setObject:group forKey:currentAlbum.identifier];
                [returnArray addObject:currentAlbum];
                [self.delegate pictureService:self fetchedAlbums:returnArray];
             };

            void (^assetGroupEnumberatorFailure)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"A problem occured %@", [error description]);                                     
            };  

            [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                                   usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator 
                                 failureBlock:assetGroupEnumberatorFailure];   
        }
}


-(void)fetchPhotosForAlbum:(Album *)album{

    ALAssetsGroup *currentGroup = [self.assetsGroups objectForKey:album.identifier];
    NSMutableArray *photos = [NSMutableArray array];
    [currentGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){         
         if(asset == nil){
             [self.delegate pictureService:self fetchedPictures:photos forAlbum:album];
             return;
         }

         [photos addObject:[self pictureForAsset:asset]];
     }];
}
```

Additionally I use two mapper methods to convert the AL-classes into my own model classes.

```
- (Album *)albumForAssetsGroup:(ALAssetsGroup *)assetsGroup{
    Album *album = [[Album alloc] init];
    album.title = [assetsGroup valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName];
    album.identifier = [assetsGroup valueForProperty: ALAssetsGroupPropertyPersistentID];
    album.assetsCount = assetsGroup.numberOfAssets;
    album.thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:assetsGroup.posterImage];
    return album;
}

- (Picture *)pictureForAsset:(ALAsset *)asset{
    Picture *picture = [[Picture alloc]init];
    picture.identifier = [((NSArray *)[asset valueForProperty: ALAssetPropertyRepresentations]) objectAtIndex:0];
    picture.thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail];
    return picture;
}
```

See the [AssetsLibrary Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730)

Comment: Then how i will get my recorded movie path?

Comment: @Astanienohpi I added an example how I could read the contents of the media library. So your movie will be one of those assets. Please note that your movie `ALAsset` object will have a `type` of ` ALAssetTypeVideo` and will probably be in the `ALAssetsGroup` with the property `ALAssetsGroupType` of `ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos`

Comment: +1 for ur brief updated answer . i will check this code . thanks

Comment: I couldn't get any video file using above code and i have apple docu too. Plz give some other solution . but i find last video was saved in App's sandbox temp floder with dynamic folder name as Capturexxxxx/capturedvideo.MOV -how to get is ? plz help me