# Unable to access iPhone Gallery in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

I am trying to access photos gallery in ios 10. But my application got crash every time. I have added required privacy permission in info.plist
Please check my code below and let me know, where i have gone wrong.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I have added Privacy - Media Library Usage Description in info.plist

I am getting below message in my console
http://prntscr.com/eg756r

Comment: Please see if Besi's update about AllAssetLibrary would help in your case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484758/how-to-call-uiimagepickercontroller-delegate-programmatically-or-forcefully-wit

Comment: is your code run at the simulator not you test device?

Comment: Add  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description    in your plist

Comment: @ezatu丶yes i am testing it in simulator. not in device.

Comment: The console error is unrelated. What line does it crash on? Have you tried adding an exception breakpoint?

Comment: were you add some other SDK include the photolibraryservice.framework,and how did you set in your info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

In 'info.plist' you should use

> Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Which will allow your app to access photo library

Answer (score 1):

in intfo.plist File you need to add  NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
 To protect user privacy, an iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0, and which accesses the user’s photo library
Please Check Below Post for more Info

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html

Comment: Although this may answer the question consider summarizing your findings so as to benefit future reader in case the link goes dead

Answer (score 0):

This should help. Here’s a mapping of each of the values that you can find and add the relevant permission key to the Info.plist:

---

Bluetooth Sharing – NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription

Calendar – NSCalendarsUsageDescription

CallKit – NSVoIPUsageDescription

Camera – NSCameraUsageDescription

Contacts – NSContactsUsageDescription

FaceID - NSFaceIDUsageDescription

Health – NSHealthShareUsageDescription & NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription

HomeKit – NSHomeKitUsageDescription

Location – NSLocationUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Media Library – NSAppleMusicUsageDescription

Microphone – NSMicrophoneUsageDescription

Motion – NSMotionUsageDescription

Photos – NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription

Reminders – NSRemindersUsageDescription

NFC - NFCReaderUsageDescription

Speech Recognition – NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription

SiriKit – NSSiriUsageDescription

TV Provider – NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription